# Ошибка в windows 10 0 000012f

Tags: windows, nvidia

Всем привет. Утром появилась ошибка "nvidia web helper 0 000012f". Я искал способы в Интернете от переустановки приложений nvidia, удаления обновлений Windows. Ничего не помогло. Дискорд тоже перестал открываться, просто серый экран. Что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDfYkZ0ycBY ? Правда, не знаю, насколько надёжен этот сайт с dll-ками

Comment: HID - это системная библиотека. Может, вирус? Нужно провериться. А может, это вовсе и не связано с HID.

Answer (score 0):

1. Перевести часы на сутки назад :-).
2. Посмотреть установленные обновления. Если вечером/ночью/утром было что-то установлено, то снести.
3. Если помогло, то временно запретить установку обновлений и ждать появления очередных, а так же мониторить Интернет на счёт ошибки. Если это связано с последним обновлением, то начнут появляться сообщения.
4. Если нет, то подумать, что делал вчера: что устанавливал, удалял. Если есть недавняя точка восстановления, то откатиться на неё.
5. Нужно ещё поизучать системный протокол приложений, там может быть дополнительная или более подробная информация.